# Given a key, how to display the ArrayList stored as the value?

Tags: java, hashmap

i have a hashmap where every key has many values(stored in a arraylist). How to display the arraylist i.e the values for a particular key in a hashmap in java??

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Do you want to use an ArrayList as a key in a Java HashMap? Maybe a few more sentences to clarify your question would be good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrintListFromHashMap {

    public static void main( String [] args ) {

        Map<String,List<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

        hashMap.put( "list",       new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("A","B","C")));

        System.out.println( hashMap.get("list") );

    }

}

$ javac PrintListFromHashMap.java 
$ java PrintListFromHashMap
[A, B, C]
```

Comment: you know you could just do `hashMap.put( "list", Arrays.asList("A","B","C"));`

Comment: @matt b Yeah, but that wouldn't be an ArrayList ( as the OP needed )

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to be able to associate *multiple values* with one key? If so, then just use either a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`, or [Google Collections `MultiMap<K, V>`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)